# How to extract all the hyperlinks and their text strings from HTML?

Tags: html, google-sheets

I have a big text file in html with a bunch of hyperlinks, e.g.:

```
"Hello I want to talk about <a href="www.google.com">Google</a> and <a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>."
```

I'm looking for a way to extract all of these from the txt file, such that I have a big Google Sheet with the following list:

1. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) — Google
2. [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) — Facebook

And so on...

However, I have basically zero coding knowledge, so am looking for a really simple explanation on how to do this (e.g. if you think I should use a Python script, I'll need to know how to do this, what to download, etc.).

Would really appreciate a helpful answer here!

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Questions really need to be specific and technical. I'd suggest reading about regular expressions. There are examples on the internet which will match hyperlinks

Comment: Where is a good place on the internet for me to ask these broad questions though?

Comment: There are plenty of good programming forums, r/learnprogramming is a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Install python on your computer

[Download here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-385/)

[How to install python video tutorial](https://youtu.be/bnhQBUEpWlg)

On your command line write pip install linkGrabber:

[image]

After that write the following commands:

```
python
import re
import linkGrabber
link = linkGrabber.Links('your url')
grab = link.find(limit=4, duplicates=False, pretty=True)
#Change the value limit as needed.
```

[image]
The results should be printed on the screen:
[image: printed urls]

Answer (score 1):

"A big text file" is a bit ambiguous. But you could try this:

1.) Open a blank Google Sheet.

2.) Copy and Paste the entire "big text file" into cell A1. If you want it to look less messy after it's in, click the cell and choose from the menu **Format > Text wrapping > Clip**.

3.) Place the following array formula into, say, cell C1:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,"</a>",0)),"href="&CHAR(34),0),"Select Col2"),CHAR(34)&">",0),"Select * Where Col2 Is Not Null"))
```

If this gives you the desired result, you can then hard-copy those results in place by selecting Column C in its entirety, hitting Ctrl-C to copy to clipboard, and then (with the column still selected) hitting Ctrl-Alt-V to Paste Special. A small clipboard icon will appear lower right on the visible screen. Click it and choose "Paste values only."

This solution is based on what you provided in the example text in your post. It also assumes that your "big text file" does not have paragraph breaks that would separate it out to different cells once pasted into Google Sheets. If it DOES break into separate cells going down Column A when pasted, you'll need to perform a couple intermediate steps:

a.) To "un-mess" Column A, select the entire column before applying **Format > Text wrapping > Clip**.

b.) Place the following formula into B1: `=JOIN(,A:A)`

c.) Change the `A1` in the formula I provided above to `B1`.

And if all of this doesn't work, consider pasting your "big text file" contents into A1 in the sheet and then sharing the link to that sheet here, being sure to set sharing permission on the link to "Anyone with the link can edit." Then I or others here can see for ourselves what you're working with and make adjustments.